# I’m looking at a PIC SoC with Wifi. Can you route the antenna far away from the chip?

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics

I’m talking about the gold PCB tracks form the centre or a circuit board the the edge where it can be clear of any interference say about 50mm.

Comment: How far? What SOC? Are you talking about a PCB etched antenna or just a connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50mm is reasonable if your trace is impedance matched… check your datasheet for details on the requirements.